# Chrome Flash player creates white rectangles

Tags: google-chrome, flash

i'm working on a flash project and we have a problem with Google Chrome. We have sometimes weird white box in flash randomly. Actually we can increase the number of redraws, but it will affect the performance and it's not a professional solution.

Is somebody already had this problem ?

Regards,

Frédéric

Answer (score 0):

Only in Chrome? Do you have the problem with another computer as well?
Whats the WMODE?

I think it's a bug in Chrome "Pepper Flash" - you can try to disable it and enable the "real" Adobe Flash Player at:

`chrome://plugins/`

Can you upload the SWF?

Comment: Yes it's only in Chrome for all computers. Seem's disapear when I change the propertie in my movieClip ( display -> render -> cache as bitmap (transparent) ).

I'm sorry, for confidentiality, I can't upload the SWF .

Thx for your answer.